# Need clarification for some basic HDFS terms

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, terminology

What is an image, a checkpoint, and what is a journal?

In one of the blogs that I have read (link: http://www.aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html), it says image in HDFS being "the inode and the list of blocks that define the metadata of the name system"; I was not sure what this sentence means...

They have also explained that "checkpoint" being "the persistent record of image stored in the NameNode's local native filesystem"; in this statement, what is referring to as a "persistent record"?

And how is journal related to those two concepts?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Those explanations on that site are very simple if you understand a generic filesystem. I'm not sure what exactly you need clarification on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is an image, a checkpoint, and what is a journal?

It's all very clearly described on that link...

> *Files and directories are represented on the NameNode by **inodes**. **Inodes** record attributes like permissions, modification and access times, namespace and disk space quotas.*
>
> *The **inodes** and the list of blocks that define the metadata of the name system are called the **image**. [...] The persistent record of the **image** stored in the NameNode's local native filesystem is called a **checkpoint**.*
>
> *The NameNode records changes to HDFS in a write-ahead log called the **journal***

As for your other questions

> "the inode and the list of blocks that define the metadata of the name system"; I was not sure what this sentence means...

If you read what an Inode is (and a block), then an image is the collection of inodes and blocks that define the metadata of the name system... There really is not another way to describe that. Maybe you need to lookup the definition of metadata?

> what is referring to as a "persistent record"?

Lookup the definition of persistent. The checkpoint is a "snapshot" of the image at a particular point in time that is stored on HDFS.

> how is journal related to those two concepts?

A journal records all changes to HDFS. The process of writing images and checkpoints makes changes to HDFS